# Check if a list element is in a list when one of it's elements is unknown

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list like the following.

```
n = [[1, 3, "String1"], [3, 2, "String2"]]
```

I want to check if one for one of these elements in the list using `in`. My problem is that I wouldn't know what the string element of the element would equal. I've already tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
import types

# Collection of data
data = [[1, 3, "String1"], [3, 2, "String2"]]

# Check to see if an element with two pre-
# determined numbers, and an unknown string
# exists.
assert [1, 3, types.StringType] in n
```

This does not work though. How can I do this properly?

Comment: are you looking for similar structure ( 2 numbers and a string) regardless of the position or check if the lists have any similar elements , in your case `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = [[1, 3, "String1"], [3, 2, "String2"]]
>>> class AnyString(str):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return isinstance(other, str)
...     
>>> check = [1, 3, AnyString()]
>>> check in data
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
assert [1,3] in (l[0:2] for l in n)
```

or:

```
assert any([1,3] == l[0:2] for l in n)
```